# Yii2 Kartik GridView Word-Wrapping

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

Has anyone been able to set up word-wrapping for a Yii GridView DataColumn?

Here is how I have set up the column:

```
 [
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'description',
    'format'=>'html',   
    'contentOptions' => [
        'style'=>'max-width:150px; min-height:100px; overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'
    ],
],
```

And no matter what settings I use I can't get the text to wrap.  I was hoping to have it wrap causing the row height to dynamically grow but it is not doing that.  Here is what the column looks like:
[image]

Anyone have any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try using options

 'options' => [
    'style'=>'max-width:150px; min-height:100px; overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'
],
```

otherwise try using   form raw an in value return the html and style you need

```
[
 'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
  'attribute'=>'',
  'format'=>'raw',   
  'value' => function($model) {
     return 'span  'style'='max-width:150px; min-height:100px; 
               overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;' . $model->description  
            .  </span> 
      },
   ],
],
```

Comment: @O2U   .. thanks  .. have you used  options o anonymous function for value?

Comment: No I haven't.  Do you have an example?

Comment: @O2U   ....  perhaps misunderstood .. in your comments you said that works and then I asked you which of the two options you chose .. (I've used in the past often anonymous functions for the value attribute)

Comment: Ahh I'm sorry.  It was the Options:  'options' => [
    'style'=>'max-width:150px; min-height:100px; overflow: auto; word-wrap: break-word;'
],

Answer (score 4):

you need override white-space: nowrap; from site.css

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\DataColumn',
    'attribute'=>'description',
    'format'=>'html',   
    'contentOptions' => [
        'style'=>'max-width:150px; overflow: auto; white-space: normal; word-wrap: break-word;'
    ],
],
```